# Eclipse, shortcut to create new Java class

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to assign a shortcut to go automatically on *New Java Class* Dialog? At the very beginning of a project when I am creating a lot of classes, it's quite annoying have to go through the '*New..*' wizard.

Here's the image of the dialog I want to reach.

[image]

Comment: Hit Ctrl + N.  By default the last new type is selected.  Hit Enter and you'll get to that wizard as long as the last new type was a Class.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Select `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys` and search for `New (Class)`. Click on `Binding`, press the keyboard shortcut you want, and click `OK` to configure the shortcut.

Answer (score 28):

Press alt+shift+n it will give you a context menu from where you can select new class,package,interface

Comment: on Mac , this shortcut doesn't work, although Cmd+ N opens up the New Wizard where i can select Class

Comment: This context menu is showing items depending if you work in normal Eclipse or Eclipse EE. In EE, it seems making new classes isnt a thing and you need to choose other all the time so its best to just do Ctrl-N.

Answer (score 14):

Ctrl+n will launch new wizard, there you can select the class/any to create new document.

Answer (score 9):

There's an icon (C icon) in the header toolbar for creating class! Its available by default Just click it!

Comment: The best answer!

Answer (score 6):

hit alt+shift+N and then click the respective first character for creating 
the respective file. For example, let's suppose you want to create a new java class:

1. Hit alt+shift+N.
2. Hit c (stands for creating java class).
3. j (it will highlight the  java package).

like this you can use shortcut keys as well as first character of the word what you want to create.

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Ctrl+3 to open the "Quick Access" Wizard and type in "java class"

Answer (score 0):

on Mac alt(option)+command+N  > displays a menu, scroll using arrow keys for appropriate selection and hit Enter.

[image]

Comment: I had this menu but now I get a different one when pressing `alt`+`cmd`+`N`. Even the program menu bar opens up the other menu which just contains of `project`, `example` and `other`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the New Java Class wizard to create a Java class. It can be invoked in different ways:

- By clicking on the File menu and selecting New → Class.
- By right clicking in the package explorer and selecting New → Class.
- By clicking on the class drop down button and selecting class.

The shortcuts for basic Eclipse file management actions are different between **Mac** and **Windows/Linux** environment.

Check it out:

[image]

Visit for more [Eclipse shortcuts](https://javatutorial.net/eclipse-shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

First press 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> and then press <kbd>c</kbd> 
then press  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

> 1. press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>
> 2. press <kbd>c</kbd> (for selecting the class)
> 3. press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> (for creating a class name)

and then class will easily created.