# How to create a java class automatically

Tags: java, android, shortcut

I am learning Android development, but now I want to practice pure java. I am using Eclipse and I was wondering if there is a shortcut/suggestion for creating a class when trying to make a new Instance of a not yet created class (non-exiting). In Android Studio the shortcut is Alt + Enter and then the IDE suggests to create a new class with that name. Example:

[image]

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339769/eclipse-shortcut-to-create-new-java-class

Comment: To the down voter, it maybe a naive question, but its not a stupid one.  To the OP, maybe the help section of eclipse or google first before posting similar questions on SO.

Comment: I tried to find it on google, but i guess I couldn't put it in the right words :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>** is the equivalent of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in IntelliJ

Also, you can paste a piece of code directly into the package explorer and Eclipse will create a class for you with that code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are refering to. But if you are looking for some kind of wizard to craeate a base skeleton class, in Eclipse you right click on the package where you want to create the class, and select New/Class.

In Eclipse you first create a Project, In the project you create one or more packages (What you see in Android Studio as com.yourdomain.appname), and inside the package/s you create the classes.

Still if you are new to Java, I recommend you do some tutorials to get acquainted with the language.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Assist/Fix** is `Ctrl`/`Cmd`+`1`. It can create types for you if you've written code as if they exist, but don't, among other things.